# Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object' - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

**ERROR**

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'.
 LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
```

This is the error I am getting.

**Controller** -

```
 public ActionResult FixturesAll()
 {
     teamMgr = new TeamManager();
     fixtureMgr = new FixtureManager();

     var team = teamMgr.GetTeams();
     var viewModel = new TeamIndexViewModel()
     {
          Teams = team.ToList(),
          NumberOfTeams = team.Count()
     };

     var fixtures = from fixtures in Oritia_entities.Fixtures
                    where fixtures.SeasonId == seasionID
                    select new FixtureModel
                    {

                        Team1 = "",
                        Team2 = "",
                        Winners = (fixtures.TeamWon+""),
                        FirstBattingTeam = (fixtures.FirstBattingTeam+""),
                        SecondBattingTeam = (fixtures.SecondBattingTeam+""),
                        Team1Score = fixtures.Team1Score + "",
                        Team1Wickets = fixtures.Team1Wickets + "",
                        Team2Score = fixtures.Team2Score + "",
                        Team2Wickets = fixtures.Team2Wickets + ""
                    };

      ViewData["Fixtures"] = fixtures;
      return View(viewModel);
 }
```

**Partial View**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits=
"System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<DataAccess.FixtureModel>>" %>
    <table>
    <% foreach (var item in ViewData["Fixtures"]
 as IEnumerable<DataAccess.FixtureModel>) // Here I am getting the error
       { %>
          <tr>                 
            <td>
                <%: item.Team1 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Team2 %>
            </td>
          </tr>
   </table>
```

**View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FunBox.ViewModels.TeamIndexViewModel>" %>
<ul>
    <% foreach (string team in Model.Teams)
       { %>
           <li><a href="<%: team.ToString() %>/">
           <%: team.ToString()  %></a> </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>

<div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("FixturesAll",ViewData["Fixtures"]); %>
    </div>
```

**Complex Classes**

```
 public class TeamIndexViewModel
 {
     public int NumberOfTeams { get; set; }
     public List<String> Teams { get; set; }
 }

 public class FixtureModel
 {
     public string Team1 { get; set; }
     public string Team2 { get; set; }
     public string Winners { get; set; }
     public string Team1Score { get; set; }
     public string Team1Wickets { get; set; }
     public string Team2Score { get; set; }
     public string Team2Wickets { get; set; }
     public string FirstBattingTeam { get; set; }
     public string SecondBattingTeam { get; set; }
 }
```

**Output of sp_help Fixtures**

```
Id          bigint (pk)
TeamID1     bigint
TeamID2         bigint
TeamWon         bigint
Date            datetime
SeasonId    bigint
ManOfTheMatch   bigint
FirstBattingTeam    bigint
SecondBattingTeam   bigint
ResultDescription   nvarchar
Team1Score  bigint
Team2Score  bigint
Team1Wickets    bigint
Team2Wickets    bigint
```

This is my overall structure and I am getting the above error.I googled but i didn't get an exact solution for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

*Thanks all for helping me and my special thanks to [**Jon Skeet**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for giving the idea*

Please see my updated query

```
 var data = from fixtures in Oritia_entities.Fixtures
                   join t1 in Oritia_entities.Teams on new { ID = fixtures.TeamID1 } equals new { ID = t1.ID }
                   join t2 in Oritia_entities.Teams on new { ID = fixtures.TeamID2 } equals new { ID = t2.ID }
                   where fixtures.SeasonId == seasionID
                   select new FixtureModel
                   {
                       Team1 = t1.TeamName,
                       Team2 = t2.TeamName,

                       Winners = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.TeamWon ?? 1)),
                       FirstBattingTeam = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.FirstBattingTeam ?? 1)),
                       SecondBattingTeam = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.SecondBattingTeam ?? 1)),
                       Team1Score = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.Team1Score ?? 1)),
                       Team1Wickets = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.Team1Wickets ?? 1)),
                       Team2Score = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.Team2Score ?? 1)),
                       Team2Wickets = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)(fixtures.Team2Wickets ?? 1))

                   };
```

I used [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487158.aspx) for converstion to string and nows it working. Thanks all.

Comment: Quick side-note: using string concatenation to convert a value to a string is really nasty. Why are you even representing numbers as strings in the first place?

Comment: @JonSkeet There will be a condition which i deleted now to make the code short in SO. It will check the int value using `a>b?c :d`.When I give '.ToString()' there is a compile time issue.

Comment: Sounds like you could probably just put brackets round the expression first...

Comment: yes.Something like `Winners =(fixtures.TeamWon==fixtures.TeamID1?t1.TeamName:t2.TeamName)`. Is there any issue or any other better way ?

Comment: You don't need brackets in that case, nor do you need `+""` which is what I was complaining about.

Comment: But `Winners` is type `string`. `TypeWon` is of `long`. But I got compile error when tried to use `ToString`. So I go for concatenation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13435/discussion-between-veekeybee-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question about this - because the type of a conditional expression isn't the type of the *condition*. So long as `t1.TeamName` and `t2.TeamName` are the correct types, you shouldn't need any conversion here. As I say, a separate question would be good. It's unrelated to this question, but you should really strive for tidy code.

Comment: ok. I am sorry. I just asked. I surly ask another question for that . But the below answers doesn't slove my issue

Comment: Thanks all for your time and effort. I cleared the issue. It is with the conversion as Jon Skeet said. Thanks again. I will post my updated query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<% foreach (var item in ViewData["Fixtures"] as IEnumerable<DataAccess.FixtureModel>)
```

try:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
```

Also try to eagerly load your entities using the `.ToList()` method:

```
ViewData["Fixtures"] = fixtures.ToList();
```

Also you might consider using view models instead of `ViewData`. It will make your code much cleaner and you will no longer rely on *magic strings*.

---

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
var fixtures = Oritia_entities
    .Fixtures
    .Where(f => f.SeasonId == seasionID)
    .ToList()
    .Select(f => new FixtureModel
    {
        Team1 = "",
        Team2 = "",
        Winners = (f.TeamWon+""),
        FirstBattingTeam = (f.FirstBattingTeam+""),
        SecondBattingTeam = (f.SecondBattingTeam+""),
        Team1Score = f.Team1Score + "",
        Team1Wickets = f.Team1Wickets + "",
        Team2Score = f.Team2Score + "",
        Team2Wickets = f.Team2Wickets + ""
    });
```

Comment: But actually I am getting the issue again

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with your LINQ query. Those string concatenations you are doing there kinda seem strange and stink.

Comment: @VeeKeyBee, see my update how you could rewrite your LINQ query.

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting your LINQ query:

```
var fixtures = Oritia_entities.Fixtures
    .Where(fixtures => fixtures.SeasonId == seasionID)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(fixtures => new FixtureModel
                    {

                        Team1 = "",
                        Team2 = "",
                        Winners = (fixtures.TeamWon+""),
                        FirstBattingTeam = (fixtures.FirstBattingTeam+""),
                        SecondBattingTeam = (fixtures.SecondBattingTeam+""),
                        Team1Score = fixtures.Team1Score + "",
                        Team1Wickets = fixtures.Team1Wickets + "",
                        Team2Score = fixtures.Team2Score + "",
                        Team2Wickets = fixtures.Team2Wickets + ""
                    }
    )
    .ToList();
```

The LINQ query is basically the same but I've put an AsEnumerable() call in between the last criteria which can be translated to SQL (which is the Where(...), and what is the type and value of seasionID btw?), and the Select(...).

Reason is that I think L2S is somehow trying to translate the Select(..) into SQL. Not sure it will work, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the controller:

```
  ViewData["Fixtures"] = fixtures.ToArray();
```

I'm not sure, but I think that's where your issue is.  If you don't use *ToArray*, then you're sending an *IQueryable* to the View, which could be problematic.

Comment: @VeeKeyBee I think it would help if you post the DB column types ... it looks like a Linq-to-Sql issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772753/linq-to-entities-format-date-in-select-query-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot... (although id tweak the try catch a bit, if you end up using it. i wouldn't recommend suppressing an error and not doing anything about it/allow it to die a silent death ;P)

```
 public string NullableObjectToString(object obj)
 {
      try
      {
          if (obj == null)
              return "";

          return (obj ?? string.Empty).ToString();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          return "";
      }
  }
```

Then

```
var fixtures = from fixtures in Oritia_entities.Fixtures
                  where fixtures.SeasonId == seasionID
                  select new FixtureModel
                  {                        
                     Winners = NullableObjectToString(fixtures.TeamWon),
                     FirstBattingTeam = NullableObjectToString(fixtures.FirstBattingTeam) // ..... you get the idea
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But there is a lot of inbuild to perform this. Kindly check my updated question